# Ember use separate child template files

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have the below template file (actually used for my component)

```
{{#each details.secs as |sec|}}
    <div class="row">
    {{#each secs.flds as |fld|}}
        // if fld.id is 'abc', use abc.hbs
        // if fld.id is 'xyz', use xyz.hbs
    {{/each}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

My question is how can I use separate sub-template files and include them in the above parent file (based on condition)

Thus if field.id is 'abc', it should use rendering logic from abc.hbs
Also abc.hbs would need the 'field' model input for rendering purpose (It's output should get appended to the main template)

Comment: Take a look at the `{{component}}` helper. Or, just write an `{{if}}` statement, using a condition like `(eq field.id 'abc')`.

Comment: but how do I then have separate child template files, with logic written inside those child files

Comment: Also see [`{{partial}}`](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/templates/rendering-with-helpers/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Ember 2.0, creating and registering our own eq (equals) helper is super easy:

```
ember generate helper eq
```

Include our equality function:

```
// app/helpers/eq.js


import Ember from 'ember';

export function eq(params, hash) {
  return (params[0] === params[1]);
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(eq);
```

And use it!

```
{{#each details.sections as |section|}}
    <div class="row">
    {{#each section.fields as |field|}}
        {{#if (eq field.id "abc")}}
            {{abc-component data=field}}
        {{/if}}
        {{#if eq field.id "xyz)}}
            {{xyz-component data=field}}
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
    </div>
  {{/each}}
```

Comment: Thx a lot...In the generated helper, I already see export function eq(..)
So do I need to replace it ?

Comment: Also const eq = (params) => params[0] === params[1]; seems to be ES6 ...can u provide ES5 equivalent ?

Comment: @testndtv 
var eq = function(arr) { return arr[0] === arr[1]

Comment: Thx...and should I remove the generated export function eq(params/*, hash*/) ?

Comment: Not sure, but why would you?

Comment: Coz it is the same name "eq" (var & function name)

Comment: also i get SyntaxError: tspui/helpers/eq.js: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (8:0)

Comment: Great..Thx a lot for your help. Really appreciate it :)